# The same build of Spotify that works like a charm on a laptop, cannot reproduce songs on another computer

Tags: permissions, user-accounts, spotify

I downloaded Spotify from [here](https://aur.archlinux.org/packages/spotify/) and installed it on my laptop, which I've been using in UK for the last year, and on my home computer in Italy where I am now.

Everything has been working and still works fine on the laptop, and, by the way, it interacts well with the phone; for instance, from the phone I can switch beteen the phone and the laptop, I can change the song from the phone while the audio is playing on the computer, and so on...

Today, upon opening Spotify on my home computer, I noticed that the *Liked Songs* tab does not show whichever song I liked while in UK, whereas in *Home* I do see some traces of what I've been listening in UK.

If this was the only issue, no problem.

In fact, the it seems I cannot play (m)any songs on my home computer.

- If I double click on a song, it starts, but after some minutes, before it ends, or sometimes just after several seconds from the beginning, the reproduction stops.
- Pulling the cursor to the right to reproduce from the beginning is ineffective: the cursor remains steady on the beginning.
- After some seconds, the banner *Can't play the current song* appears on the top.
- Basically, after "moving away" from a song, if I go back to that song, it does not play anymore.

The build of Spotify is exactly the same on the two laptops, so I think the problem is likely due to the different country, and/or to some permissions related to it where I've been using the two installs.

Are you aware of any settings that explain/solve this?

By the way, I never created a Spotify account, I always log-in with Facebook.

Comment: Complete guess, but perhaps there is some connection issue? The overall behavior really sounds as if Spotify may be having trouble connecting to the service behind the scenes.

Comment: @Anaksunaman, the connection seems just fine (happily work through VNC all the day, watch Netflix, ...).